# Height of custom TableViewCell gets cut off when scrolling

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a list of strings which I need to display in a `UITableView`. They have to have different `layouts`, so I made 4 different `TableViewCells`. In `GetCell`, I check what type the item is (the listitems are "`h_Head`" for example) and return the corresponding cell. Some entries are long and take up two lines. The problem is they get clipped off. When it initially loads, everything is fine. When I scroll past the multiline strings and I scroll back up, they get cut off. [Initial load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90d85.jpg) [After scrolling past it and back up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIppQ.jpg)

Here's my code:

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath) {
    BaseChecklistTableViewCell cell;

    var item = dict [indexPath.Row];
    string[] data = item.Split ('_');
    var type = data [0];
    var content = data [1];

    cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (new NSString ("NormalTableViewCell")) as BaseChecklistTableViewCell;

    //indented cell
    if (type.Equals ("i") && (cell == null || !cell.Key.Equals ("IndentTableViewCell"))) {
        cell = IndentTableViewCell.Create ();
    //normal cell
    } else if (type.Equals ("n") && (cell == null || !cell.Key.Equals ("NormalTableViewCell"))) {
        cell = NormalTableViewCell.Create ();
    //header cell
    } else if (type.Equals ("h") && (cell == null || !cell.Key.Equals ("HeadTableViewCell"))) {
        cell = HeadTableViewCell.Create ();
    //title cell
    } else if (cell == null || !cell.Key.Equals ("TitleTableViewCell")) {
        cell = TitleTableViewCell.Create ();
    }

    cell.setData (content);

    return cell;
}

public override nfloat GetHeightForRow (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath) {
    string item = dict [indexPath.Row];         
    SizeF size = new SizeF ((float)tableView.Bounds.Width - 40, float.MaxValue);
    nfloat height = UIStringDrawing.StringSize (item, UIFont.FromName("DINPro-Regular", 15), size, UILineBreakMode.WordWrap).Height + 20;
    return height;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `UITableView` has a standard height of 44px and that's what it is showing when scrolling back up.

You could try setting:

```
TableView.RowHeight = UITableView.AutomaticDimension;
```

The conditions for this to works are that you're using constraints.
This should make the height of your `TableCell` generic. Without having to set the height property everytime.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/tables/autosizing-row-height/ for more info. This should be the way to achieve what you're trying.